# How to find the indices of identical rows based on two columns in two different pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the follwing two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[21,80,180],[23,95,191],[36,83,176]], columns = ["age", "weight", "height"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[22,88,184],[39,84,196],[23,95,190]], columns = ["age", "weight", "height"])

df1:
   age  weight  height
0   21      80     180
1   23      95     191
2   36      83     176

df2:
   age  weight  height
0   22      88     184
1   39      84     196
2   23      95     190
```

I would like to compare the two dataframes and get the indices of both dataframes where `age` and `weight` in one dataframe are equal to `age` and `weight` in the second dataframe. The result in this case would be:

```
matching_indices = [1,2]    #[df1 index, df2 index]
```

I know how to achieve this with `iterrows()`, but I prefer something less time consuming since the dataset I have is relatively large. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column for prevent lost this information:

```
df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['age','weight'], suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))
print (df)
   index_df1  age  weight  height_df1  index_df2  height_df2
0          1   23      95         191          2         190

print (df[['index_df1','index_df2']])
   index_df1  index_df2
0          1          2
```